# How do I stack 3 jpegs vertically?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, alignment

I've three parts of a newspaper clipping saved in JPEG format that I wish to join together in a vertical alignment.

The sample can be downloaded referenced by the following link: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/58021f79

Which of Adobe's products can I use to achieve that? Photoshop? InDesign? Illustrator?

Comment: Hi patuvum, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Please tell us a bit more: as joojaa mentions, we need to know what your intended use is before we can give a good answer. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @Vincent: I edited my original post to include a sample of the newspaper clipping for anyone who wish to help me.

Answer (score 3):

(this is essentially a long structured comment)

All of the software you mention can do this. It depends a bit on the situation. Its quite clear that if you are laying the images for print then InDesign and Illustrator are the tools for the job. You might need to adjust each individual picture in photoshop, however.

Laying out for non print context I would use Photoshop, this can be a bit convoluted if the image sizes dont match. If they do match you night also just use ImageMagick instead.

Use what you know.

Comment: To my original post, I have added a URL for you to download a sample of the newspaper clipping in 3 parts.